# Dashboard lights flickering on and off after changing a starter

Tags: starter, pontiac, grand-am

Had my starter changed on a 2000 grand am. Now won't stay started putting while was started. Battery light on and dashboard lights flickering on and off. While it was running I had it in park but it was putting like it wanted to cut off which eventually it did but while I was pressing the accelerator the RPM guage wasn't moving. Any answers to what could possibly wrong with my car?

Comment: Sounds like an alternator and/or battery issue. Did you have those checked?

Comment: There should be a ground on one of the starter bolts I think. Make sure it's still attached.

Comment: Ben. I can have it checked to see. So would it be safe to say check the battery before getting a brand new alternator? Because the starter is brand new.

Comment: We are talking about a disconnected or poorly connected wire at the starter. Your starter itself is probably fine.

Comment: Ok gonna check it out. Thanks gentlemen for the input..

Comment: Ok so now jumping it won't even get it to turn over start or nothing. Can't get in touch with any of my mechanics I'm so over this issue alread... Somebody help wish I knew what to do I'd do it myself

Comment: TBH I'd have it towed back to whoever did the starter at this point.  You probably are going to need a jack, stands and a multimeter. The starter on the 3.1 is on the radiator side of the engine. Check for power on the S wire (small wire) @ the starter when someone is cranking the engine. This will allow you to check the ground wire on the starter bolt as well.

Comment: Thanks so much Ben it was exactly that.  He forgot to put the ground wire back on the bolt before tightening it.  I really appreciate your help.